# How to remove invalid character at the end of XML file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I have to process a series of XML files with jQuery that contain an invalid character after the last closing tag in the XML file. If I manually remove the character the file works perfectly using this code:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/brackets.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
```

Is there a simple way using the code above to strip this out as the file is being read?

Comment: Could you show to us an example of the xml?

Comment: It's a very plain xml file, but the last character of every file is an up-arrow. Apparently it's a limitation of the software that's building the files. Their file system always puts this character there and they can't remove it.

Answer (score 4):

The `xml` datatype would expect a valid XML document in order to call the success callback. You could instead set your datatype to `text/plain`. Your result would then be a string, which you could manipulate as you wish (remove certain characters), and manually parse the XML document after that.

You could also add your own converter for the xml datatype:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "data/brackets.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: parseXml,
   converters: {
       "text xml": function(xmlString) {
          // manipulate xmlString;
          return $.parseXML(xmlString);
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that helped point me in the right direction. I used this code to get it to work:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "data/brackets.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     dataFilter: function (response) {
         response=response.substr(0,response.length-1);
         return response;
     },
     success: parseXml

 });
```